# Accessing the request object in nuxtJS module

Tags: httprequest, nuxt.js, host, nuxtjs

I'm trying to create a nuxtJS module to make some changes to the routes based on the URL or request, i simply want to access the `request.header.host` inside a nuxtJS module but I'm unable to get it, i tried to check it `process.server`, `this`, `context` but unable to get the request object, i just want to get the full domain only, so how can I do that?

Comment: can you add some more code in here ? not enough information

Comment: Actually I have no clue on how to access the host of the website, I tried checking for `process.server` and there tried accessing the `request` object but which returned `undefined`, then I tried `process.client` and getting the host from `window.location.host` but that too didn't work as the code was executed on the server-side

Comment: Did you get the answer? I also want to get host name from request too.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the hostname in the Browser JavaScript not internally in running nuxt app. As for nuxt app, it is running locally on the server (for example http://localhost:8080).

The information regarding hostname is present in services like Nginx/Apache.

*Solution* (One of them):

Use [@nuxt/dotenv](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module#readme) and store hostname in the environment variables:

```
hostname=example.com
```

then use wherever you want in your nuxt application with `process.env.hostname`

Comment: No, actually i want to get the hostname from request object, the hostname is not fix, so can't set it in variables